# Loading multiple links in succession from a single bookmark

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

I use a website that changes based on the organization I've selected. The organization can be switched on-demand through a bookmark, but I"m always loading a specific page after I've switched organizations each time. Is there a way to create a bookmark that will load one link, then load a second link directly after in the same tab? I'm thinking that there may be a way to do this with javascript but I'm not certain.

Comment: What do you mean by "organization" ? I don't understand the purpose.

Comment: So once you have changed organisation to get to your second page, you can't bookmark that one?

Comment: flappix - it's a ticketing system that uses the same URL but changes based on which organization I've selected to file a ticket under.

Comment: @Adrian - that's what I'm doing right now - I'm just looking to see if I can make it a bit more convenient by having a single link that will select the organization and then proceed to the ticket filing url